# read a specific cells from multiple excel spreadsheets into single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to read specific cells from multiple excel spreadsheets into single pandas dataframe.

so far, I have tried this. (without a success)

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xlrd

file_list = glob.glob("*.xls")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in file_list:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(f)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    name = sheet.cell_value(rowx=9, colx=2)
    city = sheet.cell_value(rowx=15, colx=2)
    df = df.append([name,city])
```

Desired output is pandas dataframe as this

```
name   city
Tom    NY
Alex   Toronto
Anne   Atlanta
...    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: is the problem occurring at the `df = df.append()` line? or are you failing to even read in name and city in the first place? are you getting any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two sets of `[[]]` around what is being appended. With one set of brackets, it tries to add name as a row and city as a row, rather than as columns in the same row.

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xlrd

file_list = glob.glob("*.xls")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in file_list:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(f)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    name = sheet.cell_value(rowx=9, colx=2)
    city = sheet.cell_value(rowx=15, colx=2)
    df = df.append([[name,city]])
```

This will have columns named `0` and `1`, though (since you didn't define names in the creation of the dataframe), so a last step would be to rename those:

```py
df = df.rename(columns={0:'name',1:'city'})
```

Comment: great! this works. Thank you!

Comment: feel free to mark correct / upvote this answer so that others can see that the solution worked.